# How can I use the 'TimeIff' function in VBA to subtract a specific time from a user entered time in a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, time, userform

For example: users of my userform will enter a start time and end time in HH:MM AM/PM format.  I need to subtract the start time entered from 10:00 a.m and determine if there is greater than 3 hours in that time frame?  Obviously, my coding below isn't correct as it is subtracting Arrival Time instead of a set time of 10:00 a.m..  Also, I know something isn't correct with my 'If' statement but I'm not sure what?  I have tried searching several different venues for what my errors might be but am having no luck.

```
Function TimeDiff(txtDepartTime, txtArrivalTime)
    TimeDiff = Abs(txtDepartTime - txtArrivalTime)
    If TimeDiff >= 3 Then "True","False"
    End If
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`TimeSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timeserial-function) function. Note that `If...Then` in VBA is different than the IF worksheet function. Maybe worth reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements).

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim userEnteredValue As String
    Dim userEnteredDate As Date
    Dim referenceDate As Date
    Dim diffHours As Double
    Dim isLonger As Boolean

    userEnteredValue = "2:30 PM"
    If Not IsDate(userEnteredValue) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid time entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    userEnteredDate = CDate(userEnteredValue)
    If userEnteredDate > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Unexpected date exists"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    referenceDate = TimeSerial(10, 0, 0)
    diffHours = (userEnteredDate - referenceDate) * 24
    isLonger = diffHours >= 3
    If isLonger Then
        MsgBox "Time frame greater or equal 3 hours"
    Else
        MsgBox "Time frame less then 3 hours"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I only need this to run for hours and minutes...  each day they must enter a new userform for their travel so my calculation will only be based on the departtime that they have entered and the morntime that I have coded in.  I need my results to show in h:mm format.  There will be no error messages, there will only be a checkbox checked on the userform once this calculation is complete and there are more than 3 hours between those times?